# Azure AD B2C - SAML Custom Policy - Auth0.com Integration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, auth0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am attempting a proof of concept to integrate a SAML identity provider into an Azure AD B2C tenant, through which my application will be able to access via OIDC. For this, I am using Auth0.com as the IDP, for which I've created an account, application, and configured a single user whilst enabling the SAML2 add-on against the application.

I've created a custom policy, below is the `ClaimsProvider` definition, sensitive data masked.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>auth0.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Mock SAML</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="MockSaml-SAML2">
      <DisplayName>Mock SAML2</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://dev-*********.us.auth0.com/samlp/metadata/******</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="assertionSubjectName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="first_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="last_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="auth0.com" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-idp"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

The orchestration is an exact clone of "SignUpOrSignIn" but renamed, and references the `MockSaml-SAML2` technical profile. The certificate loaded into AD B2C is a self-signed certificate. Do I need to put this certificate into Auth0, or does the certificate from Auth0 need to come into B2C in some way?

I've followed the steps from the Microsoft tutorial for integrating SAML IDPs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy - but unfortunately when running the policy through B2C with the redirect URL set to jwt.ms, the URL does not contain a token, but instead `error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C An exception has occurred.`. The audit log within B2C gives absolutely no detail.

I've spent way too long on this already, if anybody has any ideas of other avenues to explore, or even a step-by-step guide to integrate Auth0 as a SAML IDP with AD B2C then that'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is also [useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Essentially, you set up the cert. on the B2C side and send the metadata to Auth0 and import it on that side. The metadata contains all the cert. info.

Of the form:

> https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/your-policy/samlp/metadata?idptp=your-technical-profile

Get the Auth0 metadata and put it here:

```
<Metadata>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://your-AD-FS-domain/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml</Item>
      </Metadata>
```

as per the docs.

Are you using AppInsights for the log?

Comment: I can't seem to find anywhere within Auth0 to actually add the metadata URL though, that's the thing! It looks like it's very manual in terms of config, I've had to specify the ACS URL, and there's a whole raft of JSON config that I could enter, but I'm not 100% certain as to what settings need to be in place. The documentation from them is not overly forthcoming: https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/saml/saml-sso-integrations/configure-auth0-saml-identity-provider#configure-saml-sso-in-auth0

Comment: I do also have App Insights configured on the policy, but nothing ever appears in the instance of App Insights to help with debug. 

This appears as the first entry on the second step of the user journey, above the reference to the `MockSaml-SAML2` technical profile:

`<ClaimsExchange Id="TrackSignInRequest" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AppInsights-SignInRequest" />`

I've got an `AppInsights-Common` technical profile which has been configured with my orchestration id.

Comment: OK - so you've implemented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy But you actually need this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thanks for all the help @rbrayb it now appears to be working. Bizarrely, I added the App Insights sections per your link, uploaded the policy again and it started to work. Removed the App Insights sections, expecting it to break again, but it continued to work. I've now managed to get the claims flowing through and have mapped them according to what the consuming app is expecting from the OIDC process.

Comment: all appears to be working correctly now, thanks for the help. I'm looking into the IDP-initiated flow, where I log in via Auth0, get redirected to B2C and then on to my app, however, I can't seem to find any documentation on it. The application is integrated into B2C with the OIDC, so I'm expecting the callback to B2C to generate an OIDC token and redirect, but so far no luck. I've read your gist - https://gist.github.com/rbrayb/98bf63a059b11c0a8d426cb1aba04925 - but that appears to be when the app is integrated via SAML and not OIDC.

Comment: IDP Initiated only applies to SAML not OIDC.

Comment: So there's no way to start from a SAML IDP, and get back to an OIDC application?

Comment: Interesting question! Maybe by using custom policies and combining the SM. Maybe use "ExternalLoginSSOSessionProvider" that caters for OAuth1 identity provider, Oauth2 identity provider, OpenID Connect identity provider and SAML identity provider. Although you don't have an external OIDC provider :-(

Comment: Well, that at least sounds hopeful, but please bear in mind that I'm very new to this topic! Do you have any pointers as to perhaps how to utilise the provider that you mention? My current tech profile uses `UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement` and that profile uses the `SamSSOSessionProvider` but this was taken from the original SAML setup article from MS. My understanding is that our B2C tenant will receive a SAML assertion (IDP initiated) and I need B2C to create the user and forward the user to the application which is already hooked up to process OIDC responses on a callback endpoint.

Comment: FYI it looks like Auth0 supports this feature when operating as the SP - https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/saml/saml-sso-integrations/configure-idp-initiated-saml-sign-on-to-oidc-apps - so it doesn't look like it's an impossible feat, just perhaps limited by current B2C capabilities.

Comment: Doing some research - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-idp-initiated-flow  We don't currently support scenarios where the initiating identity provider is an external identity provider federated with Azure AD B2C, such as Active Directory Federation Services or Salesforce. IdP-initiated flow is supported only for local account authentication in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254655/discussion-between-chris-and-rbrayb).